# How to check combobox is AutoOpen or not?

Tags: java, combobox, grid, vaadin14

I have many Combobox in my Grid.  I want to check if the status of Combobox is open. If it is opening, just close (hide) it. I use vaadin 14. For example, I will try to open (show) it first, then check the condition, and after that will close (hide) it. This picture below is combobox Opening.

```
comboBox.setOpened(true);  //this one auto Open/Show data
```

[image]

So, any advice for this? Please give me some idea.